# Serialize two api calls in react native

Tags: asynchronous, react-native, fetch

i want to call two apis in main page of my app if there is internet connectivity. how can i call them in serialize method here is code

```
componentDidMount() {

NetInfo.addEventListener(
    'change',
    this._handleConnectionInfoChange
);}
```

here is fucntion

```
  _handleConnectionInfoChange = (connectionInfoHistory) => {    
        this.setState({
        connectionInfoHistory,
        });
    console.log(this.state.connectionInfoHistory);
    if(this.state.connectionInfoHistory=='none')
    {
            console.log('no connected');
        AsyncStorage.getItem('mainSectionData' ,(err, res)=>{
        console.log(res);

        this.setState({
                    mianSectionData: res,
                    showSpiner:false
                })
    })
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('internet conneted');
        this.getData('mainSectionSliderData');  // 1st cal
        this.getData('mainSectionData');   // 2nd call
       }};
```

here is getData function

```
  getData = (_type) => { 
    //console.log(_type);
    var link,StatObject;

    switch(_type){
    case 'mainSectionSliderData':
         link=this.state.mainSectionSliderLink;
            break;
     case 'mianSectionData':
        link=this.state.mianSectionLink;
            break;}


  fetch(this.state.baseUrl+link, {
     method: 'GET'
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
     console.log('-----'+link)
     console.log(responseJson);
     switch(_type)
     {
    case 'mainSectionSliderData':
        this.setState({
            mainSectionSliderData: responseJson,
            showSpiner:false

        })

        break;

    case 'mainSectionData':
        this.setState({
            mianSectionData: responseJson,
            //showSpiner:false
        })

        break;
     }


  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
  });
 }
```

someone please help me
 my body load first with undefined how i can stop execution and wait for both calls and then load the body

Comment: Return a promise from getData function and call the second function in "then" clause

Comment: how can i do that @sumanj